# Can i put a section tag in an a tag?

Tags: html, sections

can i put a `section` tag in an `a` tag? For example:

```html
<a href="mylink">
  <section class=mysection>
    <h2>my headline</h2>
    <p>my paragraph</p>
  </section>
</a>
```

Thx so long

Answer (score 1):

technically your code is valid in https://validator.w3.org but logically this is not a good practice , you can use onClick selector , or use jQuery selector

Comment: That would make it less accessible though.

Answer (score 0):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/section)

> Permitted parents:     Any element that accepts flow content. Note that a  element must not be a descendant of an  element.

`a` [accepts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Flow_content) flow content. So yes, it's acceptable.

Answer (score -1):

[The official MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/section)  states that the permitted parents for `<section>` are all the elements that accepts **flow content** except `<address>`, the `<a>` tag accept flow content so yes you can put a section tag in an `a` tag, you can check the full list of elements that accept flow content [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Flow_content)  .

Comment: Not any or all tags.

Comment: you are right of course, i meant it is possible to nest it, in this case under the `<a>` tag

Comment: Yes. You should make that clear in your answer, not here in the comments. Your answer, as is, might get closed and deleted and downvoted.

Comment: Linking to a third party site as your answer will now definitely get this closed. Your answer must be within your question, **never** a third party link!

Comment: The link i am referring to is the MDN  official docs, i mean  are you suggesting that i copy and past the list in the answer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165491/discussion-between-george-and-rob).

Comment: I am suggesting that you form your own answer. If you want to use MDN as a reference, that's fine, but copy/paste might get you in trouble for copyright violation.